# Http Request or cURL in Windows 10

Tags: windows

How to request HTTP in `Windows 10` by default without installing any plugin?

> curl -X POST http://you-url.com/api/search

Comment: what a nice question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use the PowerShell

```
$Uri = 'http://you-url.com/api/search'
$Fields = @{
    properties='{"color": "red"}'
    maxitems='30'
    skipcount='0'
    location='country'
    userName='testing'
    password='testing'
}
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Uri -Method Post -Body $Fields | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10;
```

Comment: I think that's the easiest way